# A generic way to build a query optimization layer for Play Framework?

Tags: hibernate, caching, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

My code sometimes makes a lot of DB queries, in a rather chatty manner:

```
// Process all users:
for (User u : users) {
  // multiple queries per single user
  w = Website.find("owner = ?", u.id);
  d = Demo.find("...");
  ...

}
```

The above code is called only from special admin pages, so it doesn't have to be super fast, but I'd like to achieve reasonable performance. Is there a generic way to do this without rewriting it completely?

What I imagine is a Play Module that enables stuff like:

```
// Preprocess - warm cache
Website.findAll();
Demo.findAll();

// After the above code was run, all the data is cached in the scope of this request, so
// the following code should now not do any fetches to the database

// Process all users:
for (User u : users) {
  // multiple queries per single user
  w = Website.find("owner = ?", u.id);
  d = Demo.find("...");
  ...

}
```

Is it correct to try and build an optimization layer such as this? How would you approach it?

The advantage, as I see it, is that this allows me to "write stupid code" in the prototyping phase, and easily optimize it to a decent level when I need to. Of course it won't reach optimum performance and won't work for really large tables, but for certain tasks it might be beneficial.

Or ... should I just swallow it and rewrite the code from scratch instead, without relying on a "magical" cache layer?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate has several options to turn on second-level caching, though it is not trivial to do so. If you must use caching, you should look there.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache for an overview and http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/hibernate for the popular Ehcache option.

Of course this will affect not only your Admin-backend code, but all DB-accesses.

This said, I recommend you tune your code instead of implementing caching.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate 2nd level cache is not enabled by default with Play.
You can use the play cache directly if you need to to improve performances. Just keep in mind that the data might not be present in the cache and you might need to fetch it on a miss.

Also keep in mind the memory cost of caching.

```
for (User u : users) {
  WebSite www = Cache.get("website-"+u.id, WebSite.class);
  if(www == null){
     // multiple queries per single user
     www = Website.find("owner = ?", u.id);
     Cache.set("website-"+u.id, www, "1d");
  } 
  ...
}
```

I have never tried it but look at [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/91lJkebs-co%5B1-25%5D) regarding enabling hibernate second level cache.

You should also ensure that you have the correct index created on your database which can have a huge performance impact on heavy queries.

Comment: IF I wrote the code like that, I might as well just use a Map. I can read all entities on the start of the request, read them from the Map, and the Map will then be discarded at the end of the request. I'm trying to understand if there's a solution that requires less coding.

Comment: Play will use memcache by default which is more sofisticated than a map. You can also use ehcache as a distributed cache without changing your code. This is a much better option than a map. Of course if you feel like reinventing the wheel you can use a map, implement TTL and every feature of a cache system.